# How to use `dotnet new` template in visual studio 2019?

Tags: dotnet-cli, visual-studio-2019

I installed Visual Studio 2019 GA Released version today.

I installed this template https://github.com/Dotnet-Boxed/Templates via `dotnet new` command line

I then can use the `dotnet new` to create a project from command line.

However, the installed template does not show in this windows in Visual Studio 2019.

What the point of putting the link to install a new template from CLI but not listing new installed template in the UI?

Is this a bug or actually a missing feature?

[image: Create Asp.NET core]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-cli-templates-in-visual-studio/

in this post you can see how to enable .net core cli project templates in VS2019

Starting in Visual Studio 16.8 Preview 2 we’ve enabled a preview feature that you can turn on that enables all templates that are installed via CLI to now show as options in Visual Studio as well.  To enable this option visit the Preview Features options in the Tools…Options menu and look for the “Show all .NET Core templates in the New Project dialog” (we’re awesome at naming) checkbox and check it:

[image]

After enabling you need to restart the Visual Studio instance to get this capability.  After restarting and choosing to create a new project you’ll see some slight differences in the experience.

Comment: Is this feature still present in Visual Studio 17.2.5? I can't find it, and `dotnet new --install` installed templates don't show up in the **Create new project** window

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing feature that is still being actively planned and developed.  Look for it sometime in the .NET Core 3 timeframe.

Comment: Can you provide the source to your answer so that I can follow it to know when the feature is available?

Comment: @LxL you can see it at the bottom of the page here: https://github.com/dotnet/templating

Comment: and here is the issue linked on gitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/481

Comment: Still counting.