# Use custom .NET Core templates in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, github-actions, visual-studio-2022, project-template

I've created a bare-bone [git-repository with a Github Action](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates) which builds and publishes a nuget package containing 2 .NET templates. These templates can be installed using

```
dotnet new --install MintPlayer.AspNetCore.IdentityServer.Templates
```

Then you can create a new project using

```
dotnet new id-provider
```

But these templates aren't available from Visual Studio 2022, even though I've added the `.template.config/ide.host.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/vs-2017.3.host",
  "order": 0,
  "icon": "music_note_64.png",
  "symbolInfo": [
  ]
}
```

What do I need to do to get them into Visual Studio 2022 too? Do I need a VSIX package, like in [this example](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/template-sample/tree/main/vsix-with-template)? Is it necessary to upload a VSIX to the Visual Studio Marketplace?

- [Here are the Visual Studio SPA templates](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates)
- [Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506405/how-to-use-dotnet-new-template-in-visual-studio-2019), but it's from when this was an experimental feature. Now this option doesn't seem to exist anymore.
- [Here too](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/create-dotnet-templates-for-visual-studio-part-2/) they mention the experimental feature which I can't find anymore...

[image: Use .NET Templates in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently I was missing the following in the `template.json` file

```
"tags": {
  "language": "C#",
  "type": "project"
}
```

And it seems that you also have to take [the following](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Reference-for-template.json#:%7E:text=The%20ID%20of%20the%20group%20this%20template%20belongs%20to.%20When%20combined%20with%20the%20tagssection%2C%20this%20allows%20multiple%20templates%20to%20be%20displayed%20as%20one%2C%20with%20the%20the%20decision%20for%20which%20one%20to%20use%20being%20presented%20as%20a%20choice%20in%20each%20one%20of%20the%20pivot%20categories%20(keys)) into account:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| groupIdentity | The ID of the group this template belongs to. When combined with the tagssection, this allows multiple templates to be displayed as one, with the the decision for which one to use being presented as a choice in each one of the pivot categories (keys) |

So if you want them in Visual Studio as 2 separate templates, you need different values for `groupIdentity`